# Spring Boot JPA update multiple entities at once one to many

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I need to update all entities which filter by ID and I could do this for single entity and it works fine but how can I do this for multiple entities.

Here is successful example for single one to one update

```
@Override
public FullPack updatePack(FullPack fullPack, int id) {

    FullPack newFullPack = fullPackRepository.findByPackId(id);
    newFullPack.setPackCompose(fullPack.getPackCompose());
    newFullPack.setPackSequence(fullPack.getPackPackSequence());
    FullPack savedFullPack = fullPackRepository.save(newFullPack);


    return savedFullPack;
}
```

Assume that I will get multiple FullPack based on findByPackId then how can I update all

```
@Override
public List<FullPack> updatePack(FullPack fullPack, int id) {

    List<FullPack> newFullPack = fullPackRepository.findByPackId(id);
    //////////////////
    /////////////////
}
```

How can I do this kind of scenario

Comment: You want to update same data for all fullPack ?

Comment: Yes I need to add same data for all fullPack. One to Many mapping

Comment: Update all those using loop and use `saveAll` for list update

Comment: It would be great if you can add code section and I'm little bit confusing.

Comment: My idea similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63712293/4207306) answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the list with a for loop:

```
@Override
public List<FullPack> updatePack(FullPack fullPack, int id) {

    List<FullPack> newFullPackList = fullPackRepository.findByPackId(id);
   
    for (FullPack newFullPack : newFullPackList) {
        newFullPack.setPackCompose(fullPack.getPackCompose());
        newFullPack.setPackSequence(fullPack.getPackPackSequence());
    }

    fullPackRepository.saveAll(newFullPackList);
    
    return newFullPackList;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

With JPA, most, in not all Repository interfaces exposes a `.saveAll()` method that opens a path for you to save a collection.

You can simply save multiple FullPack like so.

```
@Override
public List<FullPack> updatePack(FullPack fullPack, int id) {

    List<FullPack> newFullPack = fullPackRepository.findByPackId(id);
    ...
    fullPackRepository.saveAll(newFullPack)
}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't make any sense, you are get list of fullPack and doing anything with it, I mean, you are saving the same object that you retrieve from database and you are not changing them. It looke like the `Bécs Norbert` answer, but your answer is incomplete!.

Comment: Now, it is better but still the same code. haha, it is okay because the developer can use `stream`, `method, anything to iterate that information.

Comment: Was simply pointing at the `saveAll` repository method that's provided by spring-data

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a Repository

```
@Query("update OrdineMacchina o set o.durataEsecuzione = o.durataEsecuzione + :incremento where o.idOrdineMacchina = :idOrdineMacchina")
@Modifying
void updateDuration(@Param("idOrdineMacchina") Long idOrdineMacchina,@Param("incremento")  Integer incremento);
```

don't foreget @Modifing. You have to @autowire the repository where you need the update.
You can write the query in JPQL or as a native query.